# Determining CRS for contoured road map of England and Wales

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, mapping, united-kingdom

I've been working with some old maps lately [1800-present] and I've had some difficulty identifying CRS/projection.

This map
[image: This map here]

has this
[image: this]

written at the bottom. Based off of this, how can I find what CRS/Projection the map is? Can you advise me something about finding CRS in general?

Comment: You could georeference it

Comment: @nmtoken yeah, except I'm trying to get some DEM data that's in 4326 to convert to this map's projection, so that I can overlay them. how do I get the dem data to match this map's projection?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html?highlight=georeferencer%20tool

Comment: yes, I've georeferenced marks before but I don't like the contortion, and I want to instead warp the DEM. is it possible to georeference the DEM layer to the map layer?

Comment: Once you have a georeferenced map you can reproject it to fit your DEM, or reproject the DEM.

Comment: got it. but how do I determine the CRS of the map? I can't seem to find it anywhere but apparently the guy who wrote it used Mercator a lot.

Comment: You could ask the creators (details in https://www.cartography.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MCT_BartsMaps.pdf)

Comment: You can just choose a CRS that you think approximates the shape of the map you want to keep, and go from there

Comment: alright, I'll try this. thanks!

Comment: Could be a cassini projection https://matplotlib.org/basemap/_images/cass.png Could also be a simple transverse mercator centered on 2°W

Comment: are these available in QGIS or ArcGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one worked for me:
[OSGB 1936 / British National Grid EPSG:2770](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/)

[image: Road map with coast data georeferenced in BNG]

To answer your questions:

> "Can you advise me something about finding CRS in general?"

You would start with looking at the age and check which map projection is usually used within a country during that time in https://epsg.org/home.html  Given a Pre-WWII age in Britain doesn't leave much choice. The first guess British National Grid has a central meridian of 2° West. So that did the trick.

Comment: Certainly looks a possible candidate at a quick glance; perhaps you could show a screenshot of the projected BNG map against the unprojected one for comparison

Comment: @Hans hey, sorry this is kind of late, but how do I use epsg.org to find the projection? I have an Australian map from around 1888, but I can't seem to find a way to select "time period" on the site.

Comment: the map in question: https://nla.gov.au/nla.obj-232658027/view

Comment: Hi Sameer, can you please make this a new question as this is getting off topic. Start with Mugnier 'grids and datums' Australia

Answer (score 2):

A second approach is to look for the "Grids and Datums" columns of Clifford Mugnier where he highlights the mapping history of a country.

This is his version for the UK:
https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/10-2003-unitedkingdom.pdf